# Can't seem to catch javascript being null

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have the following code, and i'm trying to protect when an error happens / no data is returned. As it stands, I get the error:

```
[Info] undefined (ionic.bundle.js, line 19387)
[Error] Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'data.data.length')
```

The code is like the following, understandably it's falling over because data.data.length is null / undefined (no data returned on purpose to test)

```
SaveSubmitService.saveLocal('GetData', 'NearByHubs4S', $scope.options, false).then(function (data) {
                    $scope.return = data;
                    if (typeof data != "undefined") {
                        if (data.data.length > 0) {
                            $scope.bars = $scope.return.data;
                            $scope.noNot = false;
                        } else {
                            $scope.noNot = true;
                        }
                    } else {
                        $cordovaDialogs.alert('Could not retrieve data. Are you sure you\'re online?', 'No Response', 'Ok');

                    }

                    $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');

                });
```

Oddly, it's going through the typeof as true and falling over at data.data.length being null.

I've tried doing if data == null, data == undefined, data == "undefined", data.data.length == undefined etc.

Basically i'm trying to error if the length is null!

Comment: It's not null, it clearly states that `data.data` is undefined

Comment: does `data` have a `data` property?

Comment: `if (typeof data != "undefined" && 'data' in data) { ...`

Comment: Or even just `if (data && data.data)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like your guard isn't sufficient, you need to check `data` and also `data.data`:

```
$scope.return = data;
if (data && data.data) {
    if (data.data.length > 0) {
        $scope.bars = $scope.return.data;
        $scope.noNot = false;
    } else {
        $scope.noNot = true;
    }
} else {
    $cordovaDialogs.alert('Could not retrieve data. Are you sure you\'re online?', 'No Response', 'Ok');
}
```

The guard `data && data.data` will only be true if `data` is *truthy* (any value other than `null`, `undefined`, `0`, `""`, `NaN`, or `false`, which are all *falsy*) and also if `data.data` is truthy. It won't try to check `data.data` if `data` is falsy.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not that `data.data.length` is null. The problem is that you want to use `length` property on `undefined`. That means that `data` is defined and non-null, but it does not have a `data` property, so `data.data` is undefined.

Instead of:

```
if (typeof data != "undefined") {
   if (data.data.length > 0) {
```

Do:

```
if (data && data.data) {
  if (data.data.length > 0) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
if (data && data.data) {
    if (data.data.length > 0) {   
        ...                         
    } else {
       ....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be only checking the data variable, and not its data member.

Try using an if statement such as if (data && data.data & data.data.length > 0) to check for null data.